# Draw all non-isomorphic graphs with 3 verticles

Tags: discrete-mathematics

This was a follow up on another question Where i had to prove a bipartite graph that had a bipartite complement could have a maximum of $4$ verticles. The follow up is to draw all non-isomorphic graphs with atleast $3$ verticles ( so basically $3$ or $4$ verticles) i just cant get My mind around how to draw them. All help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just draw all the non-isomorphic bipartite graphs with 3 or 4 vertices, and then delete the ones whose complements are not bipartite?

Comment: Is this the kind of thing you want ? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P%C3%B3lya_enumeration_theorem#Graphs_on_three_and_four_vertices

Comment: Thanks alot vinyl that was What i was looking for Im pretty sure!